# GCP Set label for compute instances and getting googleapiclient.errors

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

## **Using below python code to add the labels on specific instances:**

```
from pprint import pprint
import googleapiclient.discovery


compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
projectid='XXXXXXXXX'
zones=['australia-southeast1-b','australia-southeast1-a']
ip_list=[]
instance_list=[]

with open(r"D:\Users\xxxxxxxDesktop\Scripts\GCP\GCP-IP.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        ip_list.append(line)
print(ip_list)

for zo in zones:
    result = compute.instances().list(project=projectid, zone=zo).execute()
    for i in result['items']:
        for ip in ip_list:
            if i["networkInterfaces"][0]["networkIP"] == ip:
                instance_list.append({"ins_name" : i["name"], 
                                    "fp" : i["tags"]["fingerprint"], 
                                    "ins_zon":(i["zone"]).split("/")[-1]})
print(instance_list)

for instance in instance_list:
    print(instance.get('fp'))
    instances_set_labels_request_body = {
        "labels": {
            "shutdown": "no"
            },
        "LabelFingerprint":instance.get('fp')
        }
    request=compute.instances().setLabels(project=projectid, zone=instance.get('ins_zon'), instance=instance.get('ins_name'), body=instances_set_labels_request_body)
    response = request.execute()
```

=======================================================================================
**Error:**
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 412 when requesting https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxxxxx/zones/australia-southeast1-b/instances/dxxxxxx/setLabels?alt=json returned "Labels fingerprint either invalid or resource labels have changed". Details: "[{'message': 'Labels fingerprint either invalid or resource labels have changed', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'conditionNotMet', 'location': 'If-Match', 'locationType': 'header'}]">

Comment: Your code appears to be changing the fingerprint. Do not modify the fingerprint. That is a read-only field. When modifying follow the **read-modify-update** strategy. The fingerprint is used to verify that you are modifying the current version of the configuration.

Comment: The request body **should** include the fingerprint ([`instances.setLabels`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setLabels)) as proof that you are updating the current set of labels. But, you're either incorrectly obtaining this or it has been changed before you try updating the labels. Reviewing your code.

Comment: You should use `labelFingerprint` not `tags.fingerprint`. See [`labelFingerprint`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list#body.InstanceList.FIELDS.inlinedField_134)

Comment: Suggestion: you should consider **adding** `"shutdown":"no"` to the labels (get the labels, add `"shutdown"` if it doesn't exist, then update) **instead** of overwriting the labels with this value. If another script similarly overwrites the labels, your codes (theirs and yours) will conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, except I was building a bash script.

In my case I forgot to add the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` (`-H "Content-Type: application/json"`)

Curl was sending the request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and likely was breaking GCP parsing of my request.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).